# why need Array when already having ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I see besides the ability to increase the capacity, the other difference between an array and arraylist is that the latter does not allow the base type as primitive types. But since we have unboxing, which converts, saying, an Int type to Integer type, now arraylist can store any type. So why do we still need arrays?

Comment: To implement arraylist. :P

Comment: Minor issue, you wrote *...we have unboxing, which converts, saying, an Int type to Integer type...* - other way around actually. [Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) unwraps an Integer to its corresponding int value.

Answer (score -2):

Arrays are more efficient, because they have fixed size.